# how to resolve Module 'App' could not be found 'react-native' app

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am very new to react native and I was following a tutorial to try navigation through a list and detail page.

I created an Initial project which had App.js in the root directory which runs initially. 
I created my own app folder which has 'config' and 'screens' folder and also index.js.
My project structure looks like this.

[image]

I Have deleted the App.js file as I don't what that to run but I want 'Feeds.js' to run.
Here is my main 
index.js

```
 import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
 import App from './app/index';
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('DemoNavList', () => App);
```

app/index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Root, Tabs} from './config/router';

class App extends Component{
   render(){
    return <Root/>;
   }
}

export default App;
```

app/config/router.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import Feed from '../screens/Feed';
import Settings from '../screens/Settings';
import UserDetail from '../screens/UserDetail';
import Me from '../screens/Me';

export const FeedStack = StackNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: Feed,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Feed',
    },
  },
  Details: {
    screen: UserDetail,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.name.first.toUpperCase()} ${navigation.state.params.name.last.toUpperCase()}`,
    }),
  },
});

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: FeedStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Feed',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
    },
  },
  Me: {
    screen: Me,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Me',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
    },
  },
});

export const SettingsStack = StackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Settings',
    },
  },
});

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  Tabs: {
    screen: Tabs,
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsStack,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

I downloaded the code from https://github.com/spencercarli/getting-started-react-navigation

Here is the error screenshot

[image]

it would be very helpful if you could guide where I am doing it wrong.
Thanks
R

Comment: I think the problem is that you have named the folder app which maybe conflicts with the app.json file within the same directory. I am not sure why this is a problem, but i use to have this problem... Maybe rename app folder to src?

Answer (score 1):

The **appKey** in `AppRegistry.registerComponent(appKey, componentProvider)`
should match the name of your react-native project. If it is changed,it can cause problem like this. try changing 'DemoNavList' to 'FirstLookReactNavigation' as given in the git repository you mentioned.

Or you should try renaming the main folder of your react native app to 'DemoNavList'